# How long will the previous core version supported?

Tags: updating

I want to start a new project at the beginning of 2018 but I don't know if it is better to start this project with Drupal 7 or Drupal 8. Actually, I am not familiar with Drupal 8 coding and template engine.

Even though there are lots of modules that aren't available in Drupal 8 right now, such as admin menu, Date Converting module and others, I finally decided to start my project with Drupal 7, but the point that disturbs me is not knowing how long Drupal 7 will be supported. Is it 2020, 2021, or later?

Comment: Are you asking about "official" support or unofficial support? There are several companies now that continue to support Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3):

> - Drupal 7 is currently on LTS.
> - Drupal 7 LTS will end when Drupal 8 enters LTS, at which point Drupal 7 enters security fixes only mode.
> - Drupal 7 security fixes only mode ends when Drupal 8 enters security fixes only mode, and Drupal 9 enters LTS.
> - Essentially: Drupal 7 won't be EOL before development has started on Drupal 10.

Source: [Has the EOL (end of life) for Drupal 7 been announced?](https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/5kstk6/has_the_eol_end_of_life_for_drupal_7_been/)

**The simple answer is: We don't know, yet, exactly.**

Check out the following articles:

- [When is Drupal 7 End-of-Life?](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-end-of-life/)
- [Understanding the Drupal 8 and 9 Release Cycle](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/new-drupal-release-cycle/).

> Drupal 7 will likely get bug-fixes until October 2017, and official
>   security support until 2019 or 2020 at least.